# Python Tkinter Gui Hide and show key bind

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

**0 iq Question incoming**, i wanna know is there a way i can show and hide a tkinter gui with insert key, ive searched online but wasnt able to find an answer, for example like csgo menus.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to always include what you have tried and your research. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

What you are trying to accomplish can be done with this Tkinter template:

```
from tkinter import *
 
root = Tk()

# Open new window
def launch():
    global second
    second = Toplevel()
    second.title("Child Window")
    second.geometry("400x400")
 
# Show the window
def show():
    if event.keysym == "Insert"
        second.deiconify()
 
# Hide the window
def hide():
    if event.keysym == "Insert"
        second.withdraw()
 
# Add Buttons
Button(root, text="launch Window", command=launch).pack(pady=10)
Button(root, text="Show", command=show).pack(pady=10)
Button(root, text="Hide", command=hide).pack(pady=10)
 
root.mainloop()
```